# contract.deployTransaction.wait(1) not working in ethers version 6

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, ganache

To be specific I am using **ethers version 6.2.3**

Error is in this line

```js
  const deploymentReceipt = await contract.deployTransaction.wait(1);
```

Entire code I am using to deploy contract and wait

```js
const { ethers, JsonRpcProvider } = require('ethers');
const fs = require('fs-extra');
async function main() {
  const provider = new JsonRpcProvider('http://127.0.0.1:7545');

  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
    'private Key', //replace with ganache private key
    provider
  );

  const abi = fs.readFileSync('./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi', 'utf8');
  const binary = fs.readFileSync(
    './SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin',
    'utf8'
  );
  const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, binary, wallet);
  console.log('Deploying, Please wait...');
  const contract = await contractFactory.deploy();
  const deploymentReceipt = await contract.deployTransaction.wait(1); // This line has the issue.
  console.log(deploymentReceipt);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Console

```bash
Deploying, Please wait...
TypeError: no matching function (argument="key", value="deployTransaction", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.2.3)

code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
  argument: 'key',
  value: 'deployTransaction'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer for **ethers version 6** 
Changing this

```js
  const deploymentReceipt = await contract.deployTransaction.wait(1);
```

To

```js
  const deploymentReceipt = await contract.deploymentTransaction().wait(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to

```
      const deploymentReceipt = await contract.deploy();
      deploymentReceipt.wait(1);
```

Comment: no same error - no function found. I searched its the issue with **ethers version 6**.    `await contract.deploymentTransaction().wait(2);`

Answer (score 0):

```
const transactionReceipt = await contract.deploymentTransaction().wait(1);
console.log("Here is the deployment transaction: ");
console.log(contract.deploymentTransaction);
console.log("Here is the transaction receipt: ");
console.log(transactionReceipt);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to leave the comment, but if you want to return deployment transaction you need to change this:

```
console.log(contract.deploymentTransaction);
```

to this

```
console.log(contract.deploymentTransaction());
```